# Open news dataset regarding downsizing and employee layoff

Tags: data-request, companies, news

I am looking for open news dataset related to downsizing and employee layoff.

I have looked up Reuters and BBC News datasets but their categories are quite broad. Can anyone please suggest any resources for the same. I am trying to scrape various news sites but this will take a lot of time to get a good amount of data.

Comment: That looks like 4 separate data requests in one question, of which the last one (*Financial Result *) is extremely broad. Please limit your question(s) to one specific data set, give much more information than *related to*. [Read this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like)

Comment: ok i have reduced the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have scrapped few sites likes Techcrunch, Reuters , Bloomberg and few others and collected the articles related to Employee Layoff. The dataset is not that big but have around 320+ articles. Anyone is welcome for the contribution. The link for same is:
https://github.com/prayalankar2/Employee_Layoff_News_Dataset